# my stored procedure always returns zero when executed in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure for login that counts rows in three tables for matching email and password and it executes fine except when called in the code behind the output is always zero here is the stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1

    (

    @Email nvarchar(50),
    @pass nvarchar(50),
    @outres int = null OUTPUT,
    @outres1 int = null OUTPUT,
    @outres2 int = null OUTPUT,
    @outres3 int = null OUTPUT
    )
AS

     DECLARE @UserId INT



    set @outres1 =  (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Admins 
WHERE admin_Email=@Email AND admin_Pass=@pass)
if (@outres1=1)
 begin
 set @outres=@outres1
 SELECT @UserId = adminID
      FROM [dbo].Admins WHERE admin_Email=@Email AND admin_Pass=@pass

      set @outres1= @UserId
    RETURN @outres 
    end

set @outres2= (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Instructors 
WHERE inst_Email=@Email AND inst_Pass=@pass)
if (@outres2=1)
 begin
 set @outres=@outres2
 SELECT @UserId = instructorID
      FROM [dbo].Instructors 
WHERE inst_Email=@Email AND inst_Pass=@pass
  set @outres2= @UserId
 RETURN @outres 
    end
set @outres3= (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Students 
WHERE stu_Email=@Email AND stu_Pass=@pass)
if (@outres3=1)
begin
set @outres= @outres3
SELECT @UserId = studentID
      FROM [dbo].Students 
WHERE stu_Email=@Email AND stu_Pass=@pass
 set @outres3= @UserId
RETURN @outres 
end 
else
begin
set @outres=@outres3
set @outres1=0
set @outres2=0
set @outres3=0
RETURN @outres
end
```

it also saves the user ID of user if found ..and when I try to login in the browser I can't ..here's the code behind :

```
public int Validate_Login(String _Email, String _Password)
    {

        string lbl;
        string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);

        SqlCommand cmdselect = new SqlCommand();

        cmdselect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmdselect.CommandText = "[dbo].[StoredProcedure1]";

        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = _Email;

        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = _Password;

        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.Int, 4);

        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@OutRes1", SqlDbType.Int, 4);

        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@OutRes2", SqlDbType.Int, 4);

        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@OutRes3", SqlDbType.Int, 4);

        cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes3"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmdselect.Connection = con;
        int Results = 0;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            // SqlDataReader rd = cmdselect.ExecuteReader();

            cmdselect.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
            cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //cmdselect.ExecuteScalar();
            /* if (rd.HasRows)
              {
                  rd.Read();

                  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(ETB.Text, true);
                  Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
              }
              else
              {
                  lblmsg.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
              }*/
            Results = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
            int res1 = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes1"].Value;
            int res2 = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes2"].Value;
            int res3 = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes3"].Value;

            if (Results == 0)
            {
                Session["userID"] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (res1 != 0)
                {
                    Session["userID"] = res1.ToString();
                }
                else if (res2 != 0)
                {
                    Session["userID"] = res2.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["userID"] = res3.ToString();
                }

            }




        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            lbl = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmdselect.Dispose();
            if (con != null)
            {

                con.Close();

            }
        }
        return Results;


    }
```

I've tried every comment in the code and this function always returns zero ..please  help...

Comment: I have always used ExecuteReader and then closed the Reader before reading the output parameters. Finally I use SELECT in the sp to store the output parameters. Your conditions are difficult to test so I leave this as a suggestion and let's see what happens. By the way, the RETURN @outres cannot work. The parameter direction should be ReturnValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting @pass in your stored procedure however passing @Password. As a side note, please pay attention to your character casing, depending on case sensitive character collations, you may have issues.

The correct code should be like;

```
...
cmdselect.CommandText = "[dbo].[StoredProcedure1]";
cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = _Email;
cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = _Password;
...
```